# Relational database without primary key?

Tags: sqlite, database-design, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am trying to develop an android application where the user creates stories for kids. I'm using Sqlite to create my database and I want to know if my relational database is ok.

1. the story table that has a primary key story id and stores the story's name
2. the pages table where it stores the pages content and number and relates it to which story. but I don't have a primary key

   ```
   CREATE TABLE story (
       storyID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
       storyTitle TEXT
   );

   CREATE TABLE pages (
       page    INTEGER,
       content TEXT,
       storyID INTEGER
   );
   ```

Comment: This question seems to be off topic here. However - your primary key for `pages` table should be `(page, storyID)`.

Comment: First normal form demands that every row in a relational database has a primary key.  Of course your PAGE (singular) table will have a primary key.  You should create a surrogate key for each row if you don't have a natural candidate key.

Answer (score 2):

A primary key consists of one or more columns; the values in these columns uniquely identify each row.

It does not make sense for a table to have no primary key; this would imply that it would not be possible to distinguish rows, i.e., doing something with some data could be done *on any random row*.

You hava a primary key; you just don't know it, and you haven't told the database about it.
In the `pages` table, the page content is identified by both the story ID and by the page number inside the story. This means that you have a composite primary key. To get uniqueness checking and an automatic index, you should tell the database about this:

```
CREATE TABLE pages (
    storyID INTEGER,
    page    INTEGER,
    content TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (storyID, page)
);
```